# java - cannot add MouseListener to JTable

Tags: swing, jtable, listener

I just said my problem in Title... Program just don't go in that part where i add listener to table...
I need to get value of cell in selected row in first column (column 0).
Where is my mistake?

```
rezultatiTable = new JTable(data, columnNames) {


        public Class getColumnClass(int column)  {

            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);
                if (o != null) {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }
            return Object.class;
        }
    };

   System.out.println("Before Listener");

   rezultatiTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

           private void MouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
               System.out.println("IN listener");
                if (e.getClickCount() != 0)
                {
                  final JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
                  final int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                  final int column = 0;

                  final int value = (Integer) target.getValueAt(row, column);
            }
            }

    });
    System.out.println("OUT of listener");
```

I get output:
Before Listener
OUT of listener

Comment: I solved it on my own, but took me some time :-/
I just used ListSelectionListener(), so if anyone in future have similar problem, try this solution :)

Comment: you can answer and accept your own question - doing so would help future readers to find it :-)

Comment: Just a note about your code: Your MouseClicked method doesn't respect the Java naming conventions, and is private. These are two big signs that should make you realize that it can't override any method from the MouseAdapter class. Always add the @Override annotation to methods that should override another method. The correct signature is `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)`

Comment: @JBNizet good catch, didn't see it :-)

Answer (score -2):

Aunque sea demasiado tarde, puede ayudar a futuros lectores.

MouseAdapter es una clase abstracta y no se puede implementar un objeto de una clase abstracta. Debes crear una clase interna que herede de MouseAdapter, sobreescribir los métodos que necesites y enviar una implementación de esta clase interna a .addMouseListener.

*Although it is too late, this may help future readers.
MouseAdapter is an abstract class and you can not implement an object of abstract class. You must create an inner class that extends from MouseAdapter, override the methods you need and send an implementation of this inner class to .addMouseListener.*

For example:

```
//Code...

mycomponent.addMouseListener(new innerClass());


class innerClass extends MouseAdapter{

   @Override
   public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
      //Your Code
   }

}
```